# Bash store output in variable, parse, and store a few values for later use

Tags: bash, curl

So, i'm trying to write a script to create a server on Rackspace Cloud.  I've been able to get the script to successfully create a server.  Although, after the server is created i need to get a couple of pieces of data out of the output and store them in a variable for later use in the same script (going to do a couple things on the new server after creation).

Here is the script i'm using to create the server:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask user to continue or not
read -p "You are about to setup a new Rackspace cloud server. Would you like to continue (y/n)? " cont
if [ "$cont" == "y" ]; then
    echo "Starting server setup script..."

    # Ask questions to get login creds
    read -p "Rackspace Username? " username
    read -p "Rackspace API Key? " apikey

    # Get Rackspace token
    echo "Getting token..."
    token=$(curl -s -X POST https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens \
        -d '{ "auth":{ "RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{ "username":"'"$username"'", "apiKey":"'"$apikey"'" } } }' \
        -H "Content-type: application/json" \
        | python -m json.tool \
        | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access"]["token"]["id"]')
    echo "...done!"

    # Get Rackspace account id
    echo "Getting account id..."
    account=$(curl -s -X POST https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens \
        -d '{ "auth":{ "RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{ "username":"'"$username"'", "apiKey":"'"$apikey"'" } } }' \
        -H "Content-type: application/json" \
        | python -m json.tool \
        | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access"]["token"]["tenant"]["id"]')
    echo "...done!"

    # Create a new Rackspace cloud server
    echo "Creating a new Rackspace cloud server..."
    serverpassword=$(curl -s -X POST https://dfw.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2/$account/servers \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" \
        -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: test-project" \
        -T server_build.json \
        | python -m json.tool \
        | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["server"]["adminPass"]')
    echo "...done!"

    echo "Your new server has been created!"

    read -p "Would you like to continue on to setting up your new server (y/n)? " cont2
    if [ "$cont2" == "y" ]; then
        exit
    else
        echo "Here is your root password for this server (you must write this down now): $serverpassword"
        exit
    fi
else
  echo "You have chosen not to setup a new Rackspace server."
  exit
fi
```

You can see that the token and account variables are being set and used in the creation curl command.  The last curl command outputs something like this: (removed real values)

```
{
    "server": {
        "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO",
        "adminPass": "************",
        "id": "************",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://dfw.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2/...",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://dfw.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/...",
                "rel": "bookmark"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to store both the `adminPass` and `id` in two different variables.  How can i do this?  I also know that by solving this issue i will be able to refactor the script when getting `token` and `account` values by using one curl command instead of two different ones.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `adminpass` and `id` reading from prompt?

Comment: My question may have been worded wrong.  `adminPass` and `id` are values in the output of that curl command.  I'm just asterisking them because i don't want to post that info here.  What i am trying to do is take that output and store those two values in two separate variables.  Similar to the `python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access"]["token"]["id"]'` line that is getting the `token` above.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @ryanpitts1 so you have to need to copy `adminpass` and `id` variable content in anothe different variable right?

Comment: @JKB Yes, you're correct. I would take the json output of that curl command and grab `adminpass` and `id` and stick them in two separate variables.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate all the help.  I was able to figure out what i needed to do.  Maybe my original question wasn't worded in a way to get the best answers but hopefully this resolution will explain better what i was trying to accomplish.

I ended up using these commands for the 3rd curl command and to set the variables i needed:

```
serverinfo=$(curl -s https://dfw.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2/731174/servers \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" \
    -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: test-project" \
    -T server_build.json | python -m json.tool)

serverpass=$(echo $serverinfo | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["server"]["adminPass"]')
```

This allowed me to run the curl command to setup the server and then grab the `adminPass` from the output of that command and set it to the `serverpass` variable for later use.

Using this concept i was also able to remove the 2nd curl command since it was a duplicate command just to set a variable.  I can now use these commands to rub the curl once and set both variables from its output:

```
tokensinfo=$(curl -s -X POST https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens \
    -d '{ "auth":{ "RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{ "username":"'"$username"'", "apiKey":"'"$apikey"'" } } }' \
    -H "Content-type: application/json")

token=$(echo $tokensinfo | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access"]["token"]["id"]')
account=$(echo $tokensinfo | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access"]["token"]["tenant"]["id"]')
```

Hope that better explains what i was going for.  Thanks for the help, it did help me arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can grab `adminpass` and `id` from the output and store in new variable like

```
var1=$(grep "adminPass" output.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1)
var2=$(grep "id" output.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1)

echo -e $var1
echo -e $var2
```

for here i assume the third command output you redirected  to output.txt file.

Comment: How could i use this, or something similar, to eliminate the need for the second curl command.  You can see that the curls to get the `["access"]["token"]["id"]` and `["access"]["token"]["tenant"]["id"]` are identical but just getting different values from the json output.  Can i combine those somehow?  Maybe make the curl command store `["access"]["token"]` in a variable and then get `["id"]` and `["tenant"]["id"]` from that variable (via grep or something)?